# Make Test failed for Redis 4.0.10 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, redis

I am trying to compile latest stable release of Redis (4.0.10) on Ubuntu running inside Windows 10. There are no errors during "make". But when I run "make test", i get following errors towards the end. I am new to compiling stuff on ubuntu.

```
[err]: PUBLISH/SUBSCRIBE after UNSUBSCRIBE without arguments in tests/unit/pubsub.tcl
Expected '1' to be equal to '0'

[err]: PUBLISH/PSUBSCRIBE after PUNSUBSCRIBE without arguments in tests/unit/pubsub.tcl
Expected '1' to be equal to '0'

[exception]: Executing test client: child process exited abnormally.
child process exited abnormally
    while executing
"exec kill -9 $bench_pid"
    ("uplevel" body line 47)
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1 $code "
    (procedure "start_server" line 3)
    invoked from within
"start_server {} {
    # Config
    set debug_msg 0                 ; # Enable additional debug messages

    set no_exit 0                   ; # Do no..."
    ("uplevel" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1 $code "
    (procedure "start_server" line 3)
    invoked from within
"start_server {} {
start_server {} {
    # Config
    set debug_msg 0                 ; # Enable additional debug messages

    set no_exit 0          ..."
    ("uplevel" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1 $code "
    (procedure "start_server" line 3)
    invoked from within
"start_server {tags {"psync2"}} {
start_server {} {
start_server {} {
    # Config
    set debug_msg 0                 ; # Enable additional debug mess..."
    (file "tests/integration/psync2-reg.tcl" line 7)
    invoked from within
"source $path"
    (procedure "execute_tests" line 4)
    invoked from within
"execute_tests $data"
    (procedure "test_client_main" line 10)
    invoked from within
"test_client_main $::test_server_port "

Makefile:242: recipe for target 'test' failed
make[1]: *** [test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myuser/Development/Redis/redis-4.0.10/src'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm having this issue too. I tried

```
taskset -c 0 make test
```

after seeing some similar posts on Github and that didn't do the trick for me either.